# How do i query the meta data of an instance within aws and provide a json formatted output

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am after example code that will query the meta data of an instance within AWS and provide a JSON formatted output.

It can be any language as i just want to see any example.

The code must allow for particular data key to be retrieved individually.

I've tried getting information from
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html

Comment: Wow! Seems like the obvious question with no trivial answer. AWS Instance Metadata at 169.254.169.254 is a wired mix of JSON and non-JSON output. Apperently quite a few folks already tried to address this. Check out GO-based solution: http://mwhiteley.com/virtualization/2013/02/23/golang-ec2-metadata.html

Comment: Thanks that is useful.. Hopefully i can translate to C# or something similar

Comment: reworded questions

Comment: If you lock the question down a bit I believe that will help, "any language" is probably a little ambiguous. Provide some context as to the stack you are running, intent, which data are your trying to query etc

Comment: @PaulKohler I tagged this in C#.NET as that would be best for me. Should i also mention in the description? Sorry, i am new to this so all pointers would be great

Comment: @aag_noob - Have a good look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C# and can make use of the AWS SDK for .NET NuGet package for EC2 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.EC2/), you can use the EC2InstanceMetadata static class to retrieve the various metadata keys.

Documentation on the class is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=EC2/TEC2Metadata.html&tocid=Amazon_EC2_Util_EC2Metadata

Also a short blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/ec2metadata/

Code can be viewed here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/blob/master/sdk/src/Services/EC2/Custom/_bcl/Util/EC2Metadata.cs